# List custom chains with C netfilter lib

Tags: c, netfilter

I am trying to list custom chains in netfilter, but following code is giving me only the default chains in filter table when ran on Debian 11. On Ubuntu 20.04 it's listing other chains as well. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Shell:
Debian 11, kernel 5.10.0-8-amd64, iptables 1.8.7-1

```bsh
iptables -N TEST
./listchains
Chain name is INPUT
Chain name is FORWARD
Chain name is OUTPUT
```

Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-40-generic, iptables 1.8.4-3ubuntu2

```
iptables -N TEST
./listchains
Chain name is INPUT
Chain name is FORWARD
Chain name is OUTPUT
Chain name is TEST
```

C code:

```
// compile with gcc -Wall -o listchains listchains.c -lip4tc
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <libiptc/libiptc.h>

int main(void) {
 struct xtc_handle *h;
 const char *chain = NULL;
 const char *tablename = "filter";

 h = iptc_init(tablename);
  if (!h) {
   printf("Error initializing: %s\n", iptc_strerror(errno));
   exit(errno);
 }

  chain = iptc_first_chain(h);
  while (chain) {
   printf("Chain name is %s\n", chain);
   chain = iptc_next_chain(h);
 }

}
```